# exclude certain files from files found by ls

Tags: macos, ls

Having some files and folders in my current directory, for example:

```
data
log.txt
info.txt
process_data.sh
```

How to exclude the directory `data` and file `log.txt` from ls output?

I've tried:
`ls |grep -v data |grep -v log.txt`
but this command also exclude `process_data.sh` since `data` is present in its name.

I've tried:
`ls --ignore="data"`
to simply try to exclude `data` first, but received error:

```
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-@ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1%] [file ...]
```

that may indicate `--ignore` is not legal in my OS. I'm using mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a *loop* to go over the files in your directory rather than the most unreliable “ls” output (e.g. “for f in *; do grep .. done).

But to remain true to your actual question: **grep’s -w flag** (entire word) and **-E flag** (extended expression) are your friend here and should help with your precise endeavour:

```
ls | grep -vw -E ‘data|log.txt’
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of `ls` into `Perl` or `Awk`:

```
ls | perl -ne 'print unless /\bdata\b/ or /log.txt/'

ls | awk '!/\<data\>/ && !/log.txt/'
```

(There is a certain chance that this awk command won't work as expected with your version of Awk. In this case just use Perl.)

Edit: There is a way to do this with grep:

```
ls | grep -Ewv 'data|log.txt'
```